# Reorder CollectionView is not working buy adding view in cdoe behind

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I try to add my UICollectionView but the MoveItem is not working
my move event is not calling. I am not sure but I try in add in storybord it works but when I tried in code behind by adding the view in empty UIview.

This is my UICollectionViewDataSource

```
public override bool CanMoveItem(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath) {
    // We can always move items
    Console.WriteLine("Is Move");
    return true;
}
public override void MoveItem(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath sourceIndexPath, NSIndexPath destinationIndexPath) {
    // Reorder our list of items
    Console.WriteLine("Item move");
    var item = Numbers[(int) sourceIndexPath.Item];
    Numbers.RemoveAt((int) sourceIndexPath.Item);
    Numbers.Insert((int) destinationIndexPath.Item, item);
}
```

My UICollectionView class:

```
#region Computed Properties
public WaterfallCollectionSource Source {
    get {
        return (WaterfallCollectionSource) DataSource;
    }
}#
endregion

# region Constructors
public WaterfallCollectionView(IntPtr handle): base(handle) {}#
endregion

# region Constructors
public WaterfallCollectionView(CGRect frame, UICollectionViewLayout layout): base(frame, layout) {}#
endregion
public override void AwakeFromNib() {
    base.AwakeFromNib();

    // Initialize
    DataSource = new WaterfallCollectionSource(this);
    Delegate = new WaterfallCollectionDelegate(this);

}
```

my UIViewController

```
   WaterfallCollectionView Waterfall;
public ViewController(IntPtr handle): base(handle) {}

public override void ViewDidLoad() {
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    var flowLayout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout() {
        ItemSize = new CGSize((float) UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width - 20.0 f, 50.0 f),
    };
    var uICollectionView = new CGRect(0, 0, (int) UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width, (int) UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Height);
    Waterfall = new WaterfallCollectionView(uICollectionView, flowLayout);
    Waterfall.DataSource = new WaterfallCollectionSource(Waterfall);
    Waterfall.Delegate = new WaterfallCollectionDelegate(Waterfall);
    MainView.AddSubview(Waterfall);
    var log = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Hi, whehter the `CanMoveItem` method can work？

Comment: Hi I override this function in my  UICollectionViewDataSource and is not working but in my class anothor override function steel work my GetCell is work but "MoveItem" and "CanMoveItem" is not working in debug my cell is showing up but move event in not calling

Comment: Okey, could you call the long press method first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welocome to SO!

From shared code , not seeing that add `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` for `uICollectionView` . The `MoveItem` method can not invoke automatically, it need to be invoked by `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.

For example , add long press method for CollectionView as follow :

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer uILongPressGesture = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture);
collectionView.AddGestureRecognizer(uILongPressGesture );
```

Then the `longPressGesture` method implemented is :

```
private void longPressGesture(UILongPressGestureRecognizer longPressGesture)
{
    switch (longPressGesture.State)
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
            {
                Console.WriteLine("long press start");
                CGPoint touchPoint = longPressGesture.LocationInView(collectionView);
                NSIndexPath selectedIndexPath = collectionView.IndexPathForItemAtPoint(touchPoint);
                if (null != selectedIndexPath)
                {
                    collectionView.BeginInteractiveMovementForItem(selectedIndexPath);
                }
            }

            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
            {
                Console.WriteLine("long press changed");
                CGPoint touchPoint = longPressGesture.LocationInView(collectionView);
                collectionView.UpdateInteractiveMovement(touchPoint);
            }
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("long press end");
                collectionView.EndInteractiveMovement();
                break;
            }

        default:
            {
                collectionView.CancelInteractiveMovement();
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

The effect:

[image]